# Mysql Trigger Insert row Another Table using by Barcode

Tags: mysql, trigger

I Have 3 Tables:

```
1) CREATE TABLE `UrunPaketDetay`(
    `UrunPaketDetay` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `UrunPaketNo` int NULL, 
    `Tarih` date NULL, 
    `Barkod` varchar(14) NOT NULL, 
    `Urun` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `SunumSekli` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `IslemeSekli` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `PaketlemeSekli` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `Kalibre` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `Kilo` double NULL, 
    `GlazeOran` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `Uretici` varchar(190) NULL, 
    `PaletKod` varchar(50) NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`UrunPaketDetay`)
)CHARACTER SET utf8;

2) CREATE TABLE `CkisEks`(
    `CikId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `Tarih` date NULL, 
    `Musteri` varchar(190) NULL, 
    `TeslimatYer` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `CikisSaati` time NULL, 
    `AracPlakasi` varchar(18) NULL, 
    `AracTel` varchar(16) NULL, 
    `KonteynirNo` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `PaletKod` varchar(12) NULL, 
    `Kilo` double NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`CikId`)
)CHARACTER SET utf8;

3) CREATE TABLE `Ckis_Detay`(
    `CD_Id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `CikId` int NULL, 
    `Barkod` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `Urun` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `Kalibre` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `Kilo` double NULL, 
    `Uretici` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `Musteri` varchar(190) NULL, 
    `PaletKod` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `Tarih` date NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`CD_Id`)
)CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

**My Question:**

I fill up my first table. After on 2nd table i call PaletKod row. PaletKod row autofill Kilo Row on 2nd table from 1st Table.

But i need when i fill PaletKod to my 2nd table how can i select Paletkod from first table and fill my 3rd table values (`Uretici, Urun, Kilo, Kalibre` ) ?

With Trigger ?

Comment: You want simply copy the data, inserted to table 1, into tables 2 and 3, to all records in that tables with the same `PaletKod` field value?

Comment: i want to copy Uretici, Urun, Kilo, Kalibre rows to 3rd table matching "PaletKod"

Comment: Mmm... You do NOT want to copy values when data is inserted into table 1? you want to do it only when values are copied into table2?

Comment: @Akina because i need report page on table 3. so when i save 2nd table with PaletKod field after copy matching paletkod data 1st table to 3rd table.

Comment: If so - yes, use trigger AFTER INSERT and/or AFTER UPDATE on table 2. But I'd recommend to use stored procedure which inserts/updates data into table 2 (and table 3) instead of single query + trigger... especially if you need to do it in a transaction.

Comment: i new learn mysql and i dont have any idea for this. Could u help ?

Answer (score 0):

```
create trigger tr_au_CkisEks
after update on CkisEks
for each row
update UrunPaketDetay t1, Ckis_Detay t2
set t2.Uretici = t1.Uretici, 
    t2.Urun = t1.Urun, 
    t2.Kilo = t1.Kilo, 
    t2.Kalibre = t1.Kalibre
where t1.PaletKod = NEW.PaletKod
  and t2.PaletKod = NEW.PaletKod;
```

Comment: this trigger update ?  is it need after insert ?

Comment: @TazPlus Depends of a logic you need. Additionally remember the record in `Ckis_Detay` you must update may not exist - so you must check the amount of relevant records and, if it is 0, insert instead of update.

Comment: data will be insert first time to Ckis_Detay so i need insert trigger

Comment: i code this BEGIN
INSERT INTO Ckis_Detay (PaletKod, Barkod, Urun, Kalibre, Kilo, Uretici)
SELECT  PaletKod, Barkod, Urun, Kalibre, Kilo, Uretici
FROM
UrunPaketDetay
WHERE PaletKod = PaletKod;
END

But i need only same paletkod save to table 3 how can i ?

Comment: @TazPlus `WHERE PaletKod = NEW.PaletKod`. And remember, that there can be more than 1 record with the same `PaletKod` in `UrunPaketDetay` table and, as an effect, inserting more than 1 record into `Ckis_Detay`.

Comment: now i have another problem. my second table data not copied to 3rd table
Ckid, Musteri, Tarih

Comment: Data change performed from a trigger do NOT fire a "secondary" trigger. You need a chain of changes? Triggers off, use stored procedures.

Comment: how can i do it ?

Comment: [CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html). [Compound-Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-compound-statements.html).

Comment: could u say me a example ?

Comment: mmm.. I don't understand... you want me to create full code for you? Because there are some simple examples in documentation I have referenced to, and many-many examples if search this site by `"CREATE PROCEDURE" [mysql]` phrase...

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
```

INSERT INTO Ckis_Detay (PaletKod, Barkod, Urun, Kalibre, Kilo, Uretici)
SELECT  PaletKod, Barkod, Urun, Kalibre, Kilo, Uretici
FROM
UrunPaketDetay
WHERE PaletKod = PaletKod;
END

i code this trigger but when i save table 2 this trigger get all data from table 1 to table 3 
But i just need only same PaletKod data copy

Comment: Do not publish additional info as an answer. Insert it to the end of your question as its **UPDATE**.